# Dictionary additions aren't saving

Tags: c#, dictionary, save

I need to make a game for my C# class. I decided upon Battleships, quite an easy game. I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` which contains the values for all the board slots (A-J, 1-10) (for example, A5, F3, J6). I have a method that resets those keys, but checks if it's empty first (I will use it at init to actually add the keys to the dictionary first). If it is, then it uses a `for` loop inside a `for` loop (one for the letters, one for the numbers) that adds keys (A1, A2, A3..., B1, B2, B3... etc.). I added some debug code that shows what's in the key (I construct a string for the Key using the `for` variable `i`). It works fine (example: Add value -> `BoardPieces.Add(KeyToAdd, i.ToString());` and then read value -> `Console.WriteLine("Added key to {0} -> {1}", KeyToAdd, BoardPieces[KeyToAdd]);`. And it works! However, when the program returns the method and back into `Main()`, when I try and check for values in the dictionary it shows that there's nothing.
[Source Code](http://pastebin.ca/2493862) <- unsure what code to put here, so I put the source code (relevant method at line 81)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it's empty when you return to the Main method is that this method contains a seperate instance to the one which is being initialised in ResetBoard().

I would think that you probably want a single instance of Variables in your Game class, and access it from there.

This would look something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Battleships
{
    class ReadWrite
    {
        public void GetUsername()
        {

        }
    }
    class Variables
    { // Variables for the game - win, lose, board slots, user names, highscores
        public volatile Dictionary<string, string> BoardPieces = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // board slots like A1, D6 etc.
        private string username;
        private string settingsDirectory;
        private string settingsFile;
        public string _setDir
        {
            get
            {
                return settingsDirectory;
            }
            set
            {
                settingsDirectory = value;
            }
        }
        public string _setFile
        {
            get
            {
                return settingsFile;
            }
            set
            {
                settingsFile = value;
            }
        }
        public string _user
        {
            get
            {
                return username;
            }
            set
            {
                username = value;
            }
        }
    }
    class Game
    {
        private Variables vars = new Variables();

        public Variables _vars
        {
            get
            {
                return vars;
            }
            set
            {
                vars = value;
            }
        }


        public void DrawBoard() // Board should be 10x10 (1-10, A-J)
        { // should be A | B | C | D etc.
            //Console.WriteLine("   | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H ");
            //Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            //Console.WriteLine(" 1 | {0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4} | {5} | {6} | {7} ");
            // test code:
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J ");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
                }
                else
                { // {0} = 1-10, lines of the board itself
                    Console.WriteLine("I would've written lines 1-10");
                    //Console.WriteLine(" {0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4} | {5} | {6} | {7} | {8} ", i);
                    //Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        }
        public void ResetBoard()
        {
            //if (vars.BoardPieces.Count == 0)
            if (true)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // letters A-J
                {
                    for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Processing n = {0}", n);
                        string KeyToAdd = ((char)(i + 64)).ToString() + n;
                        //Console.WriteLine("The character printed is {0}", (char)(i + 65));
                        vars.BoardPieces.Add(KeyToAdd, i.ToString());
                        // Console.WriteLine("Written {0} to BoardPieces[{1}]", i, KeyToAdd);
                        Console.WriteLine("The current value in BoardPieces[{0}] is {1}", KeyToAdd, vars.BoardPieces[KeyToAdd]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game prog = new Game();
            prog.DrawBoard();
            prog.ResetBoard();
            prog.DrawBoard();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyvalue in prog._vars.BoardPieces)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}\t Value: {1}", keyvalue.Key, keyvalue.Value);
            }
            if (prog._vars.BoardPieces.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No keys found!");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get-set objects? So awesome.

Comment: Absolutely :) properties (get-set) simply provide access to a field, regardless of whether it is a primitive or a 'reference type' object.